# Defining custom gesture using Kinect SDK

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

I'm very beginner for MS Kinect programming, i'm following this book "Start Here Lean the Kinect API" by Rob Miles, all the body tracking explanation given is similar to the below code.

```
        if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.X > 
            skeleton.Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.X)
        {
            Do something.....
        // performing something based on current position of certain Joint points.

        }
```

How do i can implement something like "Microsoft Sign Language translation" application feature, i.e kinect captures couple of gestures from user then interprets the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Kinect Toolbox](http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/). This library contains the classes `TemplatedPostureDetector` (for static poses like "hands up") and `TemplatedGestureDetector` (for movements like "swipe to left"). With these classes you are able to record postures and gestures in a learning machine and detect them later. Using these classes, you can detect every kind of 2D postures and gestures.